# I need to run a AJAX Fuction from within a WP_Query but only works on first item

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have a page where users filter results from the Ultimate WP Query Search Filter plugin. The results are shown in a DIV via an AJAX call. This is working 100%. However I have another AJAX function attached to each result in the query allowing users to create a new post from search results.

(See this post for how I got that to work [Create new Wordpress post [wp_insert_post] based on results of a WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156599/create-new-wordpress-post-wp-insert-post-based-on-results-of-a-wp-query))

The problem I am having now is that when I view the wp_query results - I have a button on each record to "Add" to. When I trigger the button on the first item it works 100%. However when I click on any of the subsequent items - it still creates the post, but ignores all the values attached to it.

I am guessing I need to reset the AJAX function after each call, but unsure how to do that?

Here is the code for adding the posts: https://gist.github.com/stankobrin/4d15c29024e306b2ea43
Here is the JS / AJAX code: https://gist.github.com/stankobrin/61843fefef464e8778a3

Any help on this would be appreciated - I have spent countless hours trying everything!

S

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the element id you are taking.

Because if page has ***multiple ids with the same name*** (e.g **apftitle**). Then it will work for the **first element** only because it search for the *first occurrence* of id and work for it only

1. You can solve it by keeping the ids dynamic so it will work for all.
2. Or you can use the javascript's **[this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15223)** pointer which refers to the current element with which it is attached.

Comment: thanks for quick feedback - excuse the ignorance, but how would I make the ID's dynamic?

Comment: I havent't gone through you whole code. Can tell if you can post what is the response returned by ajax that you append in <div> with "apf-response" id.

Comment: unfortunately the apf-response only fires on the first item too. Any help implementing this would be hugely appreciated. I have tried adding a dynamic ID to the form and the add button - but same result. Only works off the first item and not the rest